# How to skip splitting delimited string inside a string array in vba

Tags: vba, excel, parsing, split

I have a VBA macro where I need to get splitStr(1) = str2,str3; splitStr(2) = str4;....

```
string1 = "str1,""str2,str3"",str4,str5,str6"
splitStr = Split(string1,",")

Debug.Print splitStr(1)
"str2
```

Thanks

Comment: How about using "" as the delimiter?

Comment: If the string1 variable has more ",", quotes would not work as delimiter

Answer (score 0):

The `Split(expression [,delimiter] [,limit] [,compare] )` function is searching through your string character by character looking for the delimiter or substring by substring depending on your delimiter.  You have a few choices:

1. Use `Split(string1,",")` and get the resulting array in splitStr as follows:

   ```
   splitStr(0) = str1
   splitStr(1) = "str2
   splitStr(2) = str3"
   splitStr(3) = str4
   splitStr(4) = str5
   splitStr(5) = str6
   ```

Then use the following code to "fix" your result the way you want

```
    splitStr(1) = Replace(splitStr(1), """", "") & Replace(splitStr(2), """", "")
    'splitStr(1) now contains str2str3
    'splitStr(2) still contains str3"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Split strings maintaining tokens within quotation marks**

Try this approach using a temporary conversion to the ►`Byte` type, which allows to loop faster through strings.

**Method**

Basically all commata **within** quotation marks are *temporarily* converted to another character (e.g. a semicolon), so that you can split as usual by substituting eventually semicolons back to normal commata.

See further explanations in the following code example:

```
Sub testByte()
  Const COMMA& = 44, QUOT& = 34, SEMI& = 59             ' constants for comma, quot.mark, semicolon
  Dim b() As Byte, i As Long, bQU As Boolean
  Dim string1$, sTemp$
' [0] string to be splitted
  string1 = "str1,""str2,str3"",str4,str5,str6"
' [1] temporary conversion of commatas in quotations to another character using the BYTE type
  b = string1                                           ' Assign string to bytes
  For i = 0 To UBound(b) Step 2                         ' check each bytes representation of character
     If b(i) = QUOT Then bQU = IIf(bQU, False, True)    ' check quotation starts
     If bQU Then If b(i) = COMMA Then b(i) = SEMI       ' change commata in quotation to temporary semicolons
  Next i
  sTemp = b                                             ' convert bytes to normal string type
' [2] split as usual
  Dim splitStr As Variant
  splitStr = Split(sTemp, ",")
' [3] check all results
  For i = 0 To UBound(splitStr)                          ' list all splitted items and ...
      Debug.Print i, Replace(splitStr(i), ";", ",")      ' ... change semicolons back to normal commata
  Next i
End Sub

'Results in immediate window
'---------------------------
'0            str1
'1            "str2,str3"
'2            str4
'3            str5
'4            str6
```

**Note**

Of course there is some intentional redundance in variables `string1` and `sTemp` allowing additional testings :-)